# I am trying to write a sanskrit mantra on autocad. When I preview the text, it is correct but as I plot the file to pdf, the 'maatra's' change

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk, cad

[The preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV1i4.png) The font and text come correctly when I preview the file but as I plot the file to pdf, the maatra's, font and lineweights change.
[The pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYI6c.png)
I tried to plot it as png, jpeg and other fonts as well but it isn't working. The colours and gradient background is also changing. I tried printing it directly through cad but the printout is also coming out wrong.

Comment: did you try png etc from the preview? ie avoiding pdf?

Comment: Are you using any external font  to write devangiri script in MTEXT ? you tagged autodesk-forge, are you using any Autodesk Platform Service API ?
Can you share a drawing with us.